# Algorithm for joining a subset of nodes in a DAG

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a DAG (or multiple DAGs), within the graph, there are subsets of nodes from which in each subset I'd wish to join as many nodes as possible without creating cycles in the DAG.

Consider the example,

[image: Simple Example]

Here I'd like to join as many as possible of the red nodes without creating any cycles in the graph. The solution is easy as all of them can be joined, see the below figure.

[image: Simple Example Solution]

Another example,

[image: Tricky Example]

Here I'd like to join as many as possible of the red nodes and also join as many as possible of the green nodes. In this example the green nodes I and F should be joined and the green nodes K and N. If the green nodes are joined as mentioned, all of the red can be joined as well.

So what I'm after is a general algorithm that for a given DAG and a set (or sets) of nodes in the DAG, join as many as possible of the nodes without creating cycles in the graph.